# After closing a question, my name appears next to a reason I did not choose

Tags: bug, questions, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question which already had 4 close votes, all with the reason **unclear what you're asking**. The question *was* clear for me, I closed it because I think it's a **duplicate** of another question.

However, after my vote, my name appeared in the information section next to the reason I did not give.

[image: "put on hold" - my name is next to a reason I did not choose]

If a question is closed for being off-topic, the UI clearly shows who were the ones that chose the final closing reason:

[image: People that chose a particular reason]

I suggest doing the same everywhere.

Note that I'm not expecting to see my reason in the info box, since it was only me who said that it was a duplicate - I'm just pointing out that I have a reason next to my name which I did not choose.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358689/wrong-close-reason-missing-duplicate-link?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yeah, it's misleading, I also wish they would fix it after all these years. +1